# Soccer Field Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, svm, naive-bayes-classifier

I would like to develop a soccer field segmentation method. For this purpose, I prepared a training image data set and annotated field and non-field pixels. Following is a gr-chromacity plot of all training samples, colored with respect to their labels.

[image]

I want to train a classifier for inferring the label of a new sample. The first approach comes to my mind is using Gaussian mixture models to model both distributions. Would you recommend another method for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest GMM at this point as the distribution of points in the space is not well-shaped enough. Even if you want to use it it's better to look at your data in PC space (i.e. using PCA). My suggestion would be:

1) Think of your features. What are they? Are you going to use these gr-chromacity as features? If yes you should know that kernel methods work better on this as the features are highly nonlinear. The image show that you need a feature mapping anyway.

2) It seems you have already thought of kernel methods as you put SVM as a tag. you can use it for classification. Might work better than GMM here. Also think of probabilistic graphical models as they have been used intensively for image segmentation and your images are structured enough (a football field has its fixed position in the image anyway).

3) If you have raw labeled dataset, I'd recommend to think of smarter features for segmentation. in gr-chromacity you already loose some information about colors which is the most important thing for you here. I would recommend taking the position of pixels into account as well. Then a PCA on the new data may reveal some more linearly separated classes.

Comment: Thanks for mind stimulating answer, I will go through your suggestions.